# how to find a table with a certain row id, add a class to the row and call button click using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have table with certain rows. Each rows has an id assigned to e.g. and a cell containing a button.

```
<tr id="69"> columns data <td><input type="Submit" name="Select" /></td></tr>
<tr id="68"> columns data <td><input type="Submit" name="Select" /></td></tr>
<tr id="72"> columns data <td><input type="Submit" name="Select" /></td> </tr>
```

using jquery how can I find a row with a certain id say '68' and add a class `hightlight` to it and fire click event of the `Select` button present inside the row

I m trying something on these lines

```
$('#templateSite tr').find('#'+data.siteId).addClass('highlight');
```

where data.siteId will be the value like 68

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for tr with a child id of id. Try:

```
$('#templateSite tr#'+data.siteId + " td").addClass('highlight');
$('#templateSite tr#'+data.siteId).find("input[type='submit']").trigger('click');
```

Comment: Sorry does not seem to work. I have alerted the first bit (`$('#templateSite tr#'+data.siteId)`) which outputs `#templateSite tr#69` and tables html is like this `<table id="templateSite" class="table-responsive show"><tr id="69">
    <td class="col-xs-1"><input type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary selectRow " value="Select" name="btnSelect"></td></tr></table>`

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or more of the html, including the table and so on.

Comment: I have created a fiddle which works, http://jsfiddle.net/nhbnk62r/ . The only other suggestion is that the class you are adding to tr might want to be added to the td instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$('tr#'+data.siteId).addClass("highlight").find("input[type='submit']").trigger('click');
```